# Managing an objects Constructors across multiple software versions

Tags: .net, oop, api-design

I'm designing a library where I am debating if I should use a constructor to initialize objects in the api's model.  My considerations are:

1. By using a constructor I can enforce what data is required to have a valid object according to the model.
2. However, by using a constructor I am curious as to how to maintain the code as it is modified in order to maintain this requirement without breaking existing code across the code base.
3. I could avoid using constructors in the object design, but I need the library to communicate to the developer using it which fields are required in order for the object to satisfy its model.

**How can I create an object model that expresses the requirement of particular properties being initialized as well as provide scalability as it relates to code maintenance?**

```
dim objV1 as new ObjectOfSomeType(Param1, Param2, Param3)
```

VS

```
dim objV1 as new ObjectOfSomeType()

objV1.Property1 = Param1
objV1.Property2 = Param2
objV1.Property3 = Param3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum required initial state for an object, i.e., data required for the object to behave in a deterministic way, should be set during construction.

If you question the capability of clients using your API to successfully construct your objects then you should publish a class containing the [Factory Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) and encourage and/or restrict the use of that.

Answer (score 2):

If initialization of some properties are required for the validity of the state of the object, then **such properties must be initialized by the constructor and made read-only**.

This will impose a requirement on the part of the class and its users which will make changes more difficult **but you cannot have the cake and eat it**.

One possible compromise is to design an **abstract base class with protected constructors** while other implementations can derive from and define other constructors and change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As you sum up, constructors are the simplest means to ensure that only valid objects are instantiated.

> However, by using a constructor I am curious as to how to maintain the code as it is modified in order to maintain this requirement without breaking existing code across the code base.

I am not quite sure what you are referring to: the risk that later you may realize that you need additional (or less) parameter(s) for creating a valid objects? IMHO **that should be mitigated by careful design, prototyping and testing prior to publishing your library**. Public APIs are very hard to change. In case of a widely used one, even broken and obsolete features need to be supported indefinitely (witness `Object.clone()` in Java). Whatever you (or clients) do to construct an object, if a required parameter turns out to be missing, it is an error. IMO it is better to detect such cases compile time than runtime, and constructors provide the simplest and easiest way to achieve this.

Other options you may want to consider:

- using a [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (you still need to have all required parameters inside the creation method, but you might be able to use some defaults for missing parameters, thus avoid breaking client code),
- using a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (similar to the above, but it gives you much greater flexibility in setting construction parameters or providing defaults).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not versed on design patterns; so take what I'm suggesting with a grain of salt and maybe see if my answer gets up/down voted before deciding to use it.

I would suggest simply following these guidlines:

1. The arguments which SHOULD be in your constructor is any data expected to be unchanged throughout the lifetime of your object.  You should NOT provide setters for these.
2. Beyond that, you can OPTIONALLY provide other arguments of variables which will be commonly set, just to make the code a little easier for the api consumer.  This is something that you know will be commonly used immediately after calling the constructor.  So, say for example, if you had a User object and nickName variable within it, you would likely want to provide an option for that in the constructor, just so the the consumer doesn't always have to call new User(); and then user.setNickName("name"); every single time they instantiate the object.

Also worth noting, you should be able to do what I described defining only ONE constructor using optional arguments, if you're using c#.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx